# Can a syllabic consonant exist between two vowels?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, syllables, phonotactics

I think it would break the sonority principle, but. Who knows...
I was thinking on a similar thing to semivowels, it seems they are only possible between vowels, if there is one between two consonants, it's not a semivowel, its a vowel, but I don't know.

Comment: Syllabic n between [i] and [i]: "peony".

Comment: Interesting... But that's supposed to be a schwa-consonant sequence, isn't it? Or at least that's what I could find.

Comment: Schwa+nasal flap seems possible, to me, but so does syllabic n.

Comment: I hope it is, and it seems possible, because I can do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is quite rare, but it arguably exists. Fante Akan has syllabic consonants which appear at ends pf words, preceded by a vowel. Such a word can be followed by a vowel-initial word, thus [ɔ̀p**ám̀ à**tàŕ] "he sewed + a dress" (accents are tone). The historical explanation is that final CV was reduced to a syllabic consonant in some contexts, so compare Akuapem Akan [àtàdé] "dress". A similar example is Logoori, where the locative clitic /mʊ̀/ optionally reduces to [m̀], so you can get [kʊ̀rɪ̀ɪ̀ndà m̀ áváànà] "to-watch+in-there+childen". Finally, in Swahili, the class 1 object prefix on verbs is [m̩]. Most verb roots which begin with vowels do not eliminate vowel hiatus (though a few do, in some contexts), giving rise to forms like [wa-me-m̩-ondok-e-a] "they went away for him" (morpheme boundaries added).

As far as I know, there are no cases of underlyingly syllabic consonants between vowels within a morpheme – such things always seem to arise by rule, of some sort.

Comment: I would really like to learn more on this subject, so if you have links, books, anything, please don't refrain from sharing!  Also, that's a good answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The Japanese letter ん represents a moraic /n̩/ sound, which always follows a vowel. Finally, it sounds like [ɴ], the uvular nasal, but elsewhere, its pronunciation assimilates to the following consonant's place of articulation. [Wikipedia's article about the letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_%28kana%29) states that it "is followed by an apostrophe in some systems of transliteration whenever it precedes a vowel", in which case it is realized usually like [ũ͍] or sometimes [ĩ].

That article gives no examples of words containing *n'*. But off the top of my head, I remembered the name of the failed [Shin'en space probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shin%27en_%28spacecraft%29), which is four morae /si-n̩-e-n̩/. A bit more digging turned up the boy's name [けんいち (Ken'ichi)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%91%E3%82%93%E3%81%84%E3%81%A1), consisting of four morae /ke-n̩-i-ti/. [Draconis](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/10559/draconis) pointed out another in a comment: [恋愛 (れんあい, *ren'ai*)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%81%8B%E6%84%9B), meaning "romantic love", is also four morae /re-n̩-a-i/. In each case, /n̩/ is a full mora but may belong to the previous full syllable depending on how your linguistics professor defines a syllable.

See also the Japanese Language Stack Exchange question [Difference between んい (n'i) and に (ni)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23434).

Comment: But, isn't there a difference between "moraic" and "syllabic"? I thought ん was usually pronounced in the same syllable as the previous vowel, except in poetry/singing.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, I thought the moraic nasal was a syllabic nasal, but everything I read says no... This moraic thing is really odd.

Comment: The example usually given is *ren'ai* "love". (Unfortunately can't type kana on here.) But no, it's usually not syllabic.

Comment: It's re.na.i phonetically?

Comment: @SavioSG If ん has to be assigned to an adjacent syllable, it's probably more honest to treat it as the previous syllable's coda. So shin.en, ken.i.chi, ren.ai. There is a Japanese set phrase beginning with ん: んです *ndesu* which confirms "it is the case", which doesn't quite fit in the answer because ん isn't followed by a vowel but may fit in an answer to a "what is a syllable?" question.